# How do I expand my <div> to properly fit more vertical content?

Tags: html, css

Whenever I try to add `margin-top: 30px` to my `box_1` and `box_2` `<div>`, my bottom `<div>` gets pushed down and disappears. It seems like my wrapper wont expand to fit the content.

How do I get a 30px gap between `top` *and* `box_1/2` *and* `bottom`?

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Circle Motion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body> 
    <div id="outer-wrapper">
        <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="top">  
            </div>

            <div id="box_1">
            <img src="chrome_400x400.png" />
            </div>

            <div id="box_2">
            <img src="firefox_400x400.png" />
            </div>

            <div id="bottom">
            <p>All Rights Reserved - CSS_maniac 2012 ©</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```css
/* My CSS */

html {
    height: 100%
}

body {
    background-color: grey;
    }

#outer-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #EAFFDB;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #EAFFDB;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#top {
    width: 900px;
    height: 110px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#box_1 {
    width: 430px;
    height: 430px;
    background-color: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

#box_2 {
    width: 430px;
    height: 430px;
    background-color: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}       

#box_1 img {
    margin: 15px 0px;
}

#box_2 img {
    margin: 15px 0px;
}

#bottom {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    clear:both;
}

/* Classes */

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: What does adding `margin-bottom: 30px;` to #top do for you?

Comment: It doesn't disappear on Firefox 14

Comment: When i add margin-bottom: 30px to top, the bottom div still disappears and the box_1 and box_2 goes straight to the bottom edge of the wrapper div

Comment: What about this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mcuJG/ (the grey on the footer was just to make it easier to see) ?

Comment: Looks just like i want it. Did you just add the margin-bottom all the way down? I cant get that to work :/

Comment: I added margins to the bottom of both divs and to the bottom of the top div. Three bottom margins.

Answer (score 0):

I've tweaked your code a little bit for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/83RZc/

Comment: I get the idea with putting the boxes in a content div - that seems great. What does the overflow: auto attribute do to the content div?

Comment: It allows the content div to expand to the height of the floated elements within it.

Comment: When I add this to the wrapper as well, I get a nasty scroll bar - the work around for that is overflow: hidden . Do you know what I should do in that case?  Thank you for your effort

Comment: I don't think you need to add an overflow property on #wrapper.